# Creating Dynamic JTrees (Controlling Root Node Visibility)

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a question about how to dynamically generate JTrees. Is there a way to set the Root Node invisible without making its children invisible too? I have tried to do the following but it shows all nodes as invisible. Keep in mind that I want to add and remove children of the Root Node at any point in time. I've added comments so you can follow what I intend to do. Let me know if they are doing something I dont need, as I am new to JTrees and don't know the conventions. I would also like to be able to select multiple children for the listener.

```
    DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode;
    rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(); //I want this invisible.

    DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(rootNode);
    JTree tree = new JTree(treeModel);

    treeModel.addTreeModelListener(this);
    tree.setRootVisible(false); // Sets everything invisible
    tree.setEditable(true); //makes tree dynamic
    tree.setShowsRootHandles(true); //supposedly allows you to see the children of the nodes.

    tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION); 
    //I would like the line above to be multi-select; however, this doesn't seem to be an option.

    DefaultMutableTreeNode table = new DefaultMutableTreeNode( "table1");
    rootNode.add(book);

    DefaultMutableTreeNode value = new DefaultMutableTreeNode( "value");
    table.add(value);
```

In the above example. Nothing is shown and when I remove the "tree.setRootVisible(false)" everything is visible including the node.

Comment: If you make the root invisible, it's (visually) not there any more. So what are the child nodes going to hang off? The concept doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I would like to have multiple "root nodes". The problem is that if no tables are loaded I don't want anything to be showing. And if a table is loaded I only want to see that table and its contents. If multiple tables are open I only want to see them. I don't want a "Root Table" with zero functionality to be constanty visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me. I based my tests on the TreeDemo from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Trees](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html). Compare your code with the tutorial code to see what the difference is.

Comment: When I run the demo I see "The Java Serires" and its two childen. When I add tree.setRootVisible(false) I only see the two children.

Comment: I don't understand the comment because that is what happens as I explained above when you use the setRootVisible(...) method?

Comment: I guess something in my code was missing, you're right it works fine in the tutorial. I'll have to see what I'm doing differently in my code :)

Answer (score 7):

A very late answer, but I have just had the same problem.
Ensure to expand your root node, so that its children become visible :

```
yourTree.expandPath(new TreePath(root.getPath()))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the difference between the code in the question and in the TreeDemo is that the tree demo creates and adds all its nodes *before* creating the actual tree. If the nodes are to be added dynamically (after the tree is created) it should be done through the TreeModel. Otherwise no events saying the tree has changed will be generated. At least that is what the tutorial seems to say about editing the node's "content", might be the same issue:

> Note that although DefaultMutableTreeNode has methods for changing a
>   node's content, changes should go through the DefaultTreeModel cover
>   methods. Otherwise, the tree model events would not be generated, and
>   listeners such as the tree would not know about the updates.

[Someone's solution](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/65014)

Answer (score 0):

A very late answer also, I'm a java beginner and had the same problem so it may help.

setRootVisible(false) also hides all nodes for me so I added setShowsRootHandles(true) to show all nodes :

```
tree.setRootVisible(false);
tree.setShowsRootHandles(true)
```

I hope it helps !
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display